# How to Identify html text with corresponding header-like objects?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Below is an html example but my use case involves different types of unstructured text. What is a good generic approach to tie (label) each of the 2 text paragraphs below with their parent header (SUMMARY1)? The header here isn't really a header tag  but its just a bolded text. I am trying to extract and identify text paragraphs along with their corresponding header sections irrespective of whether the header is really a standard header  or something like below:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <title>Europe Test  - Some stats</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Watch videos and find the latest information.">
<body>
<p>
    <b><location">SUMMARY1</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a region in <location>Europe</location>
      where the climate is good.
    </p>
    <p>
      Total <location>Europe</location> population estimate was used back then.
    </p>

<div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to come up with a JSON like this:
{SUMMARY1: ['This is a region in Europe where the climate is good','Total Europe population estimate was used back then']}

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Could you share a URL for this kind of article? I might have an out-of-the-box idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately, I don't have a url, my starting point is this kind of html text stored in files.

Comment: Not a problem, could you provide a full html source of this kind of article?

Comment: I guess you should either try to include it into the question itself, or if it does not allow that because of the content length limitations, use a third-party like pastebin temporarily please. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, updated the html in the original question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was initially thinking about using the [`newspaper` module](http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but failed to find a way to get the `SUMMARY1` as the only part of a "summary" or "description" or anywhere else on the resulting `Article` object. In any case, check out this module - may really help you to parse HTML articles.

But, if using `BeautifulSoup`, you may initially locate the header, then get the next `p` elements with [`find_all_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import newspaper


html = """
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <title>Europe Test  - Some stats</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Watch videos and find the latest information.">
<body>
<p>
    <b><location value="LS/us.de" idsrc="xmltag.org">SUMMARY1</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      This is a region in <location>Europe</location>
      where the climate is good.
    </p>
    <p>
      Total <location value="LS/us.de" idsrc="xmltag.org">Europe</location> population estimate was used back then.
    </p>

<div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
        </body>
    </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
header = soup.find("b")
parts = [p.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for p in header.find_all_next("p")]
print({header.get_text(strip=True): parts})
```

Prints:

```
{'SUMMARY1': [
     'This is a region in Europe where the climate is good.', 
     'Total Europe population estimate was used back then.']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using BeautifulSoup it should be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'your html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
header = soup.find('b')
print(header.text)
first_paragraph = header.findNext('p')
print(first_paragraph.text)
second_paragraph = first_paragraph.findNext('p')
print(second_paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<html>
    <div>
        <p>
            <b><location value="LS/us.de" idsrc="xmltag.org">SUMMARY1</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            This is a region in <location>Europe</location>
            where the climate is good.
        </p>
        <p>
            Total <location value="LS/us.de" idsrc="xmltag.org">Europe</location> population estimate was used back then.
        </p>
    </div>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
items = soup.select("b")[0]
paragraphs = ' '.join([' '.join(data.text.split()) for data in items.find_parent().find_next_siblings()])
print({items.text : paragraphs})
```

Output:

```
{'SUMMARY1': 'This is a region in Europe where the climate is good. Total Europe population estimate was used back then.'}
```

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this so that all paragraphs and corresponding parents are identified irrespective of whether the parent is a bolded header or a standard <h*> tag header or something else? Also, how about reverse lookup? As in, given any line of a paragraph, determine its parent (header)? Thanks.